# Does blockdev --flushbufs reliably sync to disk?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, block-device

I am using `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/mmcblk0p1` in one of our shell scripts.

I have assumed that it has same effect as sync for raw block device access.

I wonder whether it's safe to assume at the end of `blockdev --flushbufs` all delayed writes are completed for that device?

(The man page mentions ioctls so I think it should be blocking?)

Comment: "logical dupe" http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98568/difference-between-blockdev-flushbufs-and-sync-on-linux

Comment: It looks like flushbufs might just drop the _read caches_, not sync the writes. http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg39184.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing at above link, but drop cashes is dangerous, I assumed that it must write cached data to the flash itself. I used it like that. I write to raw partition using `dd` and then call `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/mmcblk0p1` to ensue data is written to flash(eMMC). If `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/mmcblk0p1` is not doing that then what should i use ? any hint ?

Comment: How is drop caches "dangerous"? That's just not true. [`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) is documented as non-destructive operation. I'd suggest `sync` or [`syncfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syncfs)

Comment: what i meant is, if is caches are dropped before committing changes to flash it would be dangerous.

Comment: And if my keyboard summoned a large autonomous truck to drive over my pet cat that would be dangerous too.

Comment: :D :D I don't understand what would be effect of `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/mmcblk0p1` I thought it has same effect as `sync` but to be used when working on blockdevice directly and skipping filesystem. Now if it is not doing that then things might fail.

Comment: Maybe you should just ask your question, instead of listing the assumptions. You really wanted to ask "what exactly does (commandXYZ) do?"

Comment: I updated it a bit more. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On the emmc , this thing does not work unfortunately ( same for the sd cards on general ). the ioctl is not implemented on the upstream drivers.

So far I thought that it does what it says till I realize that it is not doing anything.

The mmcqd is not affected by the ioctl BLKFLSBUF and processes the asynchronous mmc request pending in the queue. It takes what it takes, but if the poweroff -f is performed right after executing :
blockdev --flushbufs 
or
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
The block dev and the file system won't be fully synchronized on your emmc or sd card.

Answer (score 0):

`blockdev --flushbufs` sends an *ioctl* to flush the device's own write cache if any, and may not be reliable (the command may not be implemented in the driver, device or even get intercepted on its way). It would only flush data that has already been sent to the device by the OS, and ensure it's been written on the physical media.

If you want to sync data from a mounted filesystem, you can use `sync()` or one of its variants. Normally the applications themselves should care about syncing their data safely to disk, and the data is also flushed by the OS when unmounting the filesystem.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98568/55904) for more details on the difference between `blockdev --flushbufs` and the various sync syscalls.